# .NET Core: security access based on group membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'll make this post short and get straight to the seriousness of the situation. Our application has the concept of "Organizations" which are comprised of "Members". We recently found a huge security flaw in our application. If a Member that does not belong to a specific Organization (but is logged into the application) gets access to a URL for any of that Organization's pages, he/she can access that page.

Is there something built into .NET Core 3.0 or Web API that would allow us to stop users from being able to access Organization pages that user is not a Member of? The only way I can think to do it is check if the Member (based on their MemberId) belongs to the Organization (based on OrganizationId). However, that  check would have to be added to every single API controller. There has to be a better way! Any help is appreciated...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: This is not token auth or any type or role based access. This is specific to our application. I would have to write something custom. Some kind of handler, no?

Comment: Hmmm... ActionFilter sounds promising. Anyone have experience at creating a global ActionFilter to handle user access via the API request? Any tips?

Comment: If you can provide some example code of how pages or other resources are organized and identified as belonging to a given organization and how you're handling the user identity/authentication and authorization at present, that would be helpful in identifying a path forward. As suggested, this is very much within the scope of ASP NET Core's OOB authorization capabilities.

Comment: Typically you'd want to setup your authentication such that the organization id is set as a claim for the user. Then you can define database filters and authorization checks that check against this claim value.

Answer (score 0):

Decided that I am going to:
1) Create a custom exception
2) Throw it in a base repo class that all of my derived classes are inheriting from
3) Propagate it up and catch it at the base controller class using an ActionFilter
4) Return 403 (w/ custom exception error message) to user (Angular)
5) Have the Angular HTTP interceptor handle the error message, meaning show to user

If anyone has a better idea please let me know.